# How to distinguish whether to prune Docker images with --all in Ansible?

Tags: docker, ansible, devops

In an Ansible playbook, we can request what amounts to a call of

```
docker image prune
```

by this:

```yaml
- name: Clean up Docker images
  docker_prune:
    images: yes
```

However, there doesn't seem to be a way to request `--all`, i.e. to prune all images that are not used in a container. It doesn't do so by default, anyway:

```
TASK [role : Clean up Docker images] ***
ok: [server] => {
    "changed": false, 
    "images": [], 
    "images_space_reclaimed": 0
}
```

Apparently, `images_filters` has options that do not directly correspond to CLI Docker options:

> A dictionary of filter values used for selecting images to delete.
> For example, `dangling: true`.
> See the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/#filtering) for more information on possible filters.

Unfortunately, that option isn't documented at all; removing dangling images is the default, so what does `true` even effect?

How can I tell Ansible to perform the equivalent of `docker image prune --all`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to correctly guess that `dangling: true` means "prune *only* dangling". Thus, this task does what we want:

```
- name: Clean up Docker images
  docker_prune:
    images: yes
    images_filters:
      dangling: false
```

```
TASK [role : Clean up Docker images] ***
ok: [server] => {
  "changed": false,
  "images": [
    {
      "Untagged": "docker.io/ruby:alpine"
    },
    {
      "Untagged": "docker.io/ruby@sha256:cbcf3c98e7bd7dfd0a535c91a6c186eed483680cefe0c99ed1ed46d6efbb0e7b"
    },
    {
      "Deleted": "sha256:47c30d96ab20f3004776ff14fce824960f94dd8ba40f689a839d250befa8924e"
    },
    {
      "Deleted": "sha256:1ffdfb9e5dfb8e61532391c9624539dfe6695fa535d8dd375019ae910bc6a263"
    },
    {
      "Deleted": "sha256:59d90740fdbf9dae0a8c7e824cdb25b6636ab7c56d5d90a1ed52cc523123ef7f"
    },
    {
      "Deleted": "sha256:e0b257ffac8a68382fb702142120625ee8c7c579dd22143ac8ee02e0bb23e1eb"
    },
    {
      "Deleted": "sha256:d6fd80a889d96453e9b6b27c475952f0cc90fa6c0d1d922024cb4158362e16eb"
    },
    {
      "Deleted": "sha256:1bfeebd65323b8ddf5bd6a51cc7097b72788bc982e9ab3280d53d3c613adffa7"
    }
  ],
  "images_space_reclaimed": 51040409
}
```